# Boost for android error with NDK

Tags: android, c++, boost, android-ndk

I'm trying to add support for BOOST in my android application which contains the c++ library. I'm following these instructions:

https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/Boost-for-Android

However, I'm getting the error when running the command:

```
build-android.bat C:/Users/user/.android-sdk/ndk-bundle
```

Error:

```
Building boost version: 1.53.0
ERROR: %* is not a valid NDK root
```

What could be causing this? Is the root incorrect? I've been struggling for hours on this ...

Comment: Please check the values in the "Environment variables". ;%ANDROID_NDK%;

Comment: Why would that make a difference ?

Comment: I'm not using the variable but instead just giving the filepath as an argument

Comment: I found it easier to build boost for android by writing Android.mk files for all the parts of boost that I wanted to build, which I then invoke from my main Android.mk using `call all-makefiles-under`.

Answer (score 0):

As per Ajitha's comment, ndk-bundle directory is different to the directory specified in the environmental variable. for eg, my environmental variable points $ANDROID_NDK_ROOT to `C:\NVPACK\android-ndk-r10e`, whilst the ndk-bundle (which can be accessed via Android Studio > File > Project Structure > SDK Location > , points to `C:\Users\%user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle`

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?